# Server Tags with HTML and Code Blocks inside

Tags: c#, asp.net, runatserver, server-tags

I'm trying to do something like this:

`<asp:ListItem><div><%= Message.Success %></div></asp:ListItem>`

but it gives me this error:

> ASP.NET runtime error: Code blocks are not supported in this context.

Any ideas as to how to work around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Binding Expression inside Controls `<%# %>`.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <%# Message.Success %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

However this does not work in a `ListItem`. You will need to add that item with code if you want the `Message.Success` to be displayed.

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = Message.Success, Value = "0" });
```

Comment: would `DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "<div>" + Message.Success + "</div>", Value = "0" });` work?

Comment: No, because you cannot use html elements in a ListItem. It would just visibly render as `<div>Message</div>`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm building a kind of html generator, do you know any other server elements that does not accept html inside? or where to find them?

Comment: I think only Controls that use a Key-Value pair from the ListItem (Like dropdownlist, checkbox, radiobutton etc).